# Sphinx Delta Indexing issue

Tags: php, indexing, sphinx, delta

I have created delta indexes. and merging them using following commands

sudo /usr/local/sphinx/bin/indexer --merge messagecenter_quotations_reply messagecenter_quotations_reply_delta  --rotate

But It only merges if I restart sphinx. if i run this command with out restarting sphinx I do not get any results .

Answer (score 1):

The indexer sends a SIGHUP to the searchd daemon to tell it to restart. It finds the process to signal by checking the PID file set in your sphinx configuration. Check the 'searchd' section of your config file for the 'pid_file' value, and make sure it is set to a file that is readable by the indexer. Also, make sure you're running the indexer process with sufficient permissions to signal the searchd process; for example, if searchd is running as root, you'll also need to run the indexer as root.